# A 2D shadow algorithm

Tags: algorithm, flash, 2d, shadow

I am planning on making a game that utilizes light (and shadows) as part of the gameplay, however I can't think of an efficient algorithm to implement them and I'm sure there is an elegant solution.

[image: An illustration of what I want to do]

The white area is directly illuminated by light, light grey is illuminated by the walls that are directly illuminated and dark grey is darkness.

I wish to find those areas in an efficient manner. (real time, with the light being able to move)

Although not realistic, that is the simplest way I could think of my problem, any other implementation that includes direct light and reflected light is welcome.

...

My first attempt would be to draw lines from the light to the perimeter of the screen and find the first wall they intersect. But repeating this algorithm for every illuminated part of the wall to mark "ambient" light is not feasible.

Also note, the game is in Flash so I don't think I can utilize the gpu.

Comment: And you wonder what those GPUs are spending their time on...  Have you considered using a proprietary library that has access to the GPU to do this efficiently?

Comment: I was always wondering how shadows could slow my computer so much in games. Now I know.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention, I was also planning to make this in Flash.

Comment: You might want to add a `flash` tag to your question.  And here's a [flash related dicussion on shadows](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?354488-Casting-shadow-Light-in-2d).

Comment: Would you say that the lighting in this game is what you're after? http://www.kongregate.com/games/Jiggmin/neverending-light

Comment: @PinnyM: that's only true if there are many polys. In 2D, it's much simpler, especially with very few lines. This is nowhere near as complex as 3D lighting.

Comment: Google for "shadow volumes."  These are for 3d, but you're trying to do much the same in 2d.  Computing shadow volumes correctly is pretty tricky.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Ryan's answer.

In a 2d grid, mark every point of the screen as lit. Then for every wall on the screen (in order of closeness to point) draw a shadow behind them as such:[image: point to wall shadow] Before going to the next wall, first check which parts of it are lit and which are not, as to not draw the shadow twice. Mark all the walls for which the shadow was drawn for the next step, as these are the probably lit walls. (we should check again before the next part)

For every lit line segment (wall) first check if any wall intersect the segment. For every intersection split the lit segment in 2 at the intersection.[image: linear light to wall intersection]

For the end points of every line segment, repeat the first part in a temporary array, and at the end add all the lit points into the final array.

The first part should go over all the points on the screen and all the points on the walls once. So O(area+length of walls), and depending on the complexity of the scene (number of walls, and interesections the second part should apply the first part about 20 times.

This may work in real time, however make sure to store the lit areas while the lights are not moving.

Comment: I think rather than starting with a bright rooms and then drawing grays, it would be more easier to start by assuming everything is dark and draw the illuminated parts instead.

Comment: That would improve things, you would still need to draw some shadows back, but overall it would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to draw all light lines, just the important ones. For example, with one point light source and one line, you only need to solve two intersections.

For reflected lighting, you would start with a point light of intensity n, then every time this light intersects a wall, you split the wall into smaller segments, and add a linear light source of intensity n-1 on the illuminated segment. You can do this as many times as you liked.

Comment: As I understand, I can construct polygons behind every line which I fill with shadow. However this means I will have to fill about 1/4 of the area of the screen for every line. Assuming 20 lines that would mean 5 areas of screen. Assuming again 400*600 screen. That would mean at least 400*600*5 operations. If I have 200 points of wall initially illuminated, then I will not be able to run it in reasonable time. As a comparison my algorithm would have involved drawing lines of length 2-300 towards every point of the perimeter. So 2000 lines and about 300*2000 operations for one light source.

Comment: If you order the walls by distance to source then the algorithm can be improved to filling the screen about once, by checking if further walls are illuminated before constructing polygons. The "penumbra" still remains the biggest problem, as even filling the screen 200 times is too difficult.

Comment: @csiz: the math for a line light source is only slightly more complicated than calculating two point lights. The screen size and the length of the line light does not matter.

Comment: @Ryan: At first I thought there were special cases were I couldn't consider just the line, however those are solved by first a check if the lines intersect.